# How to create custom repeater field which contains select menu and input field in wordpress without using any plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Here I created the custom repeater field which works perfectly for input field, but I want select menu instead of input box, so I modified the above code, but it is not working. Whenever I click on update button, it adds a new repeater field and previously selected values are not displayed. Can anyone help?

````
   ```
 <?php
    add_action('admin_init', 'gpm_add_meta_boxes', 2);
    
    function gpm_add_meta_boxes()
    {
        add_meta_box('gpminvoice-group', 'Paper Publication Information', 'Repeatable_meta_box_display', 'paper_publication', 'normal', 'default');
    }
    
    function Repeatable_meta_box_display()
    {
        global $post;
        $gpminvoice_group = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ra_publications', true);
        wp_nonce_field('gpm_repeatable_meta_box_nonce', 'gpm_repeatable_meta_box_nonce');
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('#add-row').on('click', function() {
                    var row = $('.empty-row.screen-reader-text').clone(true);
                    row.removeClass('empty-row screen-reader-text');
                    row.insertBefore('#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last');
                    return false;
                });
    
                $('.remove-row').on('click', function() {
                    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
        <table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $publications = array('deccan-herald' => "Deccan Herald", 'kannada-prabha' => "Kannada Prabha", "times-now" => "Times Now", "vijayavani" => "Vijayavani");
    
                if ($gpminvoice_group) :
                    foreach ($gpminvoice_group as $field) {
                ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="15%">
                                <select name="publicationName[]" value="<?php if ($field['publicationName'] != '') echo esc_attr($field['publicationName']); ?>">
                                    <?php foreach ($publications as $publicationKey => $publicationValue) : ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $publicationValue; ?>"><?php echo $publicationKey; ?></option>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
    
                            </td>
                            <td width="70%">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter article url" name="publicationUrl[]" value="<?php if ($field['publicationUrl'] != '') echo esc_attr($field['publicationUrl']); ?>" />
                            </td>
                            <td width="15%"><a class="button remove-row" href="#1">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                else :
                    // show a blank one
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="Title" title="Title" name="TitleItem[]" /> -->
                            <select name="publicationName[]">
                                <?php foreach ($publications as $publicationKey => $publicationValue) : ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $publicationValue; ?>"><?php echo $publicationKey; ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <!-- <textarea placeholder="Description" name="TitleDescription[]" cols="55" rows="5">  </textarea> -->
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter article url" name="publicationUrl[]" />
                        </td>
                        <td><a class="button  cmb-remove-row-button button-disabled" href="#">Remove</a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
    
                <!-- empty hidden one for jQuery -->
                <tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
                    <td>
                        <select name="publicationName[]">
                            <?php foreach ($publications as $publicationKey => $publicationValue) : ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $publicationValue; ?>"><?php echo $publicationKey; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <!-- <textarea placeholder="Description" cols="55" rows="5" name="TitleDescription[]"></textarea> -->
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter article url" name="publicationUrl[]" />
    
                    </td>
                    <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add another</a></p>
    <?php
    }
    add_action('save_post', 'custom_repeatable_meta_box_save');
    function custom_repeatable_meta_box_save($post_id)
    {
        if (
            !isset($_POST['gpm_repeatable_meta_box_nonce']) ||
            !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['gpm_repeatable_meta_box_nonce'], 'gpm_repeatable_meta_box_nonce')
        )
            return;
    
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
            return;
    
        if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
            return;
    
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ra_publications', true);
        $new = array();
        $invoiceItems = $_POST['publicationName'];
        $prices = $_POST['publicationUrl'];
        $count = count($invoiceItems);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if ($invoiceItems[$i] != '') :
                $new[$i]['publicationName'] = stripslashes(strip_tags($invoiceItems[$i]));
                $new[$i]['publicationUrl'] = stripslashes($prices[$i]); // and however you want to sanitize
            endif;
        }
        if (!empty($new) && $new != $old)
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'ra_publications', $new);
        elseif (empty($new) && $old)
            delete_post_meta($post_id, 'ra_publications', $old);
    }
    
    ?>
```
````